# How to create Database and Tables programatically when installing c# application on client

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an application which I completed, I finished everything but I can't figure out a problem and the problem is :

Im using Sql Server Express 2008 r2 as a database I install the database engine on client, but how to create Database and tables when application runs because I cannot Create everything on my computer, because he runs a brand new Sql Server Express 2008 r2 install, so is it a good practice to do this ? :

Example: When my first form loads to have a Load Event in the first form that loads that will do a SqlCommand like :

```
IF db_id('testDB') IS NULL
BEGIN
     Create Database testDB
END
```

and Tables after is it a good practice to do it this way? But Im afraid that will slow down checking everytime for this conditions, is it another way to do this. This database purpose is Local(I don't want SqlCompact or Sql Express 2012 LocalDB) I want to use Sql Server Express 2008 r2.

Comment: If your connect string specifies a database, you'll likely know if it exists before you can execute a command.

Comment: Good point, how do I know the Connection ? it seems everything lays around CustomAction ...?

Answer (score 0):

You should create the database only once, using an CustomAction in your installer. Once installed the application, there is no need to check if database exists.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368066(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Hmm ok, very fast answer as usual, in your opinion is it good practice to install a brand new Sql Server Express 2008 r2 on each instal on client instead of using a Single Database somewhere ?

Comment: @user3144640: That completely depends on what you want to do with the data.  However, installing SQL Server on each machine is unusual.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I see you are a Microsoft MVP. I just want momentarily the data to be stored Local and later to Scale. I don't want to do anything with the data and I have chose Sql Server Express 2008 r2 for many Operating Systems that it supports. Sql Compact Edition was great but it does not support Xp...

Comment: @user3144640 Your question was about how to create the database and tables for your application. Now, if you ask me about the deployment model of your project, it will heavily depends on your business requirements. Based on that, you can choose between plain file storage, xml, file based databases, server based databases, cloud services..

Comment: @Oscar I will mark it as answer but how do I Save Connection String I need CustomAction for this also ? I just need any database that supports many Operating Systems.

Comment: You can use the methods in the ConfigurationSettings class to write the connection string to your app.config file. http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.configuration.configurationsettings(v=vs.110).aspx
Or you can create a custom dialog to ask the user for credentials when installing and build internally a connection string. It depends, as always, of your users requirements.